# Ticking hide from product page randomly ? Magento2

Tags: product, frontend, magento-2.0.4, page

I migrated installation from magento 1.9.2.2 to 2.0.4 and everything went well, except its ticking hide from product page for some images of products, some products have this problem, some dont, there is no rule.I can resovle this by manually unticking hide from product page but it would take years. On products that have this problem I also have problem its showing product details raw text on top of page, I 'll attach screenshot of how that looks. [image] .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a script to do a mass update to unselect this option for all products.

The worse but faster way is to change these values in DB directly:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` SET `disabled`=0;
```

Note: it's no a good practice to make changes to the DB directly, only try this on dev after making a backup.